# Are "Need Download link for X" anime allowed?

Tags: discussion

Just a bit curious. Are questions allowed that request for Download links of a particular anime series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. This would be allowing people to directly give links to illegal sites which provide downloads and fansubs.

Also not allowed is: "Where can I watch/read X online?"

Comment: oh, just thought if that was allowed! Got it cleared :P
Thanks :)

Comment: @looper: What if the?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Oh, I didn't want to post it. Decided that my question was stupid and accidentally clicked Add Comment ^^'